# Vb error: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

We are writing a recipe program as practice for GCSE and I keep getting this error when the code gets to this code:

```
Dim ingredients as string() = recipe(0).split(New Char() {","})
```

I am trying to retrieve from a file and put it into a text box, I have declared recipe array and have made sure that the file is there. I have also got a stream reader to read the file.

Any help would be brilliant!

Comment: Note that there are several answers on that linked dupe, [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/791010) is specific to VB

Comment: *Declaring* an array and *initializing* it are 2 different things; there is not enough code there to be able to offer more help.  Having a file, reader and array doesnt mean they are used correctly or in the right order.